# Evaluating Math Function through Simplification

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I am going through a computer science text book and it is simplifying an equation but I don't understand how it gets the answer. How does 5n get multiplied out? If you multiply both sides by 2 to get rid of the denominator wouldn't 5*(n/2) just be 5n not (5n + 5n)?

[Question runthrough screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZGou.png)

Comment: Um, no.  5*(n/2) would be neither of those.  It'd be 5n/2.

Comment: Could you explain why

Comment: Explain why 5*(n/2) = 5n/2?  Seriously?  Because.... well associativity of multiplication and notation of fractions as multiplicative inverses, I guess if you are algebraicly inclined.  Or as fractions defined as division (the inverse of multiplication) because "5 times (n divided by 2) = 5 times ((n times 1) divided by 2) = (5 times times n) times (1 divided by 2) = (5 times n) divided by 2".

Comment: I agree with the proposer. There is an error in the third equation of Ch.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going on the sheet:

$T(n) = 2T(\frac n 2) + 5n$

So $T(\frac n 2) = 2T(\frac n 4) + \frac {5n} 2$

Plugging the second back into the first:

$T(n) = 2[ 2T(\frac n 4) + \frac {5n} 2 ] + 5n$

$= [2\times2T(\frac n 4) + 2\times \frac{5n} 2] + 5n$

$ = 2\times2T(\frac n 4) + 5n + 5n$.

Comment: I see, would have been much easier to follow if the textbook said plug back in, thanks a lot!